# Property 'address' does not exist on type 'BaseContract'

Tags: hardhat, openzeppelin-contracts, hardhat-deploy

I have TimeLock contract that extends TimelockController from OpenZeppelin contracts:

```
contract TimeLock is TimelockController {
 
  constructor(
    uint256 minDelay,
    address[] memory proposers,
    address[] memory executors,
    address admin
  ) TimelockController(minDelay, proposers, executors, admin) {}
}
```

I am using hardhat to deploy the contracts in which hardhat deploys TimeLock contract before it deploys Box contract. I am retrieving the TimeLock contract address in Box contract deploy script but it's showing error for `transferOwnership(timeLock.address);`

> Property 'address' does not exist on type 'BaseContract'

```
const deployBox: DeployFunction = async function (hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
    
    const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, network } = hre;
    const { deploy, log, get } = deployments;
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
    
    log("Deploying Box ...");
    const box = await deploy("Box", {
        from: deployer,
        args: [],
        log: true,
    });

    const boxContract = await ethers.getContractAt("Box", box.address);
    const timeLock = await ethers.getContract("TimeLock");

    const transferOwnershipTx = await boxContract.transferOwnership(timeLock.address);
    await transferOwnershipTx.wait(1);
    log("Box ownership has been transferred to TimeLock contract");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `contract.target` or `await contract.getAddress()` instead. Ethers v6 has different interfaces to Ethers v5.

https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/contract/#BaseContract-target

It's possible you have differing versions installed. Frameworks and tool sets have not settled on a commonly supported version.